# Unable to clone this repository in Windows 8 RC with Github for Windows

Tags: github-for-windows

I get the following error message when trying to clone one of my GitHub repositories in Windows 8 RC using GitHub for Windows:

*Unable to clone this repository.
Please check your internet connection.*

- When I try to clone the same repository in Windows 7 using GitHub for Windows, it succeeds.
- Cloning in Windows 8 progresses to about 9% before the error message appears.

I've checked the log file TheLog.txt, that says there's an error setting certificate verify locations:

```
2012-06-02 20:28:12.5876|INFO|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Activating GitHub.ViewModels.AboutViewModel.
2012-06-02 20:28:57.4916|INFO|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Deactivating GitHub.ViewModels.AboutViewModel.
2012-06-02 20:28:57.4916|INFO|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Closed GitHub.ViewModels.AboutViewModel.
2012-06-02 20:28:59.0532|INFO|GitHub.Models.RepositoryModel|Cloning [repository-url].git
2012-06-02 20:28:59.0532|INFO|GitHub.Helpers.GitRemote|Cloning '[repository-url].git' to 'Spotify-Metro-Style-App' in directory 'C:\GitHub
2012-06-02 20:28:59.0562|INFO|GitHub.PortableGit.Helpers.GitEnvSetupExtensions|Configuring SSH Agent: :
2012-06-02 20:28:59.0562|INFO|GitHub.PortableGit.Helpers.GitEnvSetupExtensions|PATH is C:\Users\EivindGussiås\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_0812189c12ccff4584523d6efce294a33dd2332a\cmd;C:\Users\EivindGussiås\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_0812189c12ccff4584523d6efce294a33dd2332a\bin;C:\Users\EivindGussiås\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_0812189c12ccff4584523d6efce294a33dd2332a\mingw\bin;C:\Users\EivindGussiås\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\7VOQ2HDO.HJX\5506OVG3.2LE\gith..tion_8f45a2159c87c850_0001.0000_70cd4637d2963700;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\WINDOWS\System32
2012-06-02 20:28:59.0782|INFO|GitHub.IO.ObservableProcess|git.exe clone --progress --recursive [repository-url].git "Spotify-Metro-Style-App" 
2012-06-02 20:29:02.2949|WARN|GitHub.Extensions.StandardUserErrors|Showing user and error Please check your internet connection.
GitHub.IO.ProcessException: Cloning into 'Spotify-Metro-Style-App'...
error: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:\Users\EivindGussiås\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_0812189c12ccff4584523d6efce294a33dd2332a/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
 while accessing [repository-url].git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
2012-06-02 20:29:02.2949|WARN|GitHub.ViewModels.ShellViewModel|User error encountered: Unable to clone this repository.
```

- In Windows 7, where cloning the repository succeeds, nothing is written to TheLog.txt.
- In Windows 8 RC the same error occurs on any repository I try to clone.
- I sign in to Windows 8 using a Microsoft account, which has been a problem in Windows 8 CP with GitBash, because the user name is automatically set to include norwegian characters not supported by GitBash. As you can see, my home directory is C:\Users\EivindGussiås\.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclosure: I am a developer at GitHub.*

This should be fixed in the v1.0.8.4 update we just released.

Comment: I just upgraded the client, and now it works like a charm. Thanks for quick and excellent support! :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Win 7, running the latest version of GitHub for Windows. Can't clone repositories, and no clue how to resolve the issue. Sent an email to support at github... could you some help here.

Comment: Same issue as its_me, I downloaded GitHub for Windows today and I can't clone my repos.

**Edit:**
To fix in Windows 7, in GitHub for Windows click on tools then options.  From there try updating the default storage directory, then try again. It worked for me.

Comment: Updating the default storage also worked for me on Windows 8. Thanks

Comment: New install, I have version 1.0.3.3.2
Check for updates indicates that I've got latest version.
Changing the default storage directory didn't work for me.

Comment: same issue in version 1.0.33.2 (that error after 9%). Updating default storage dir doesn't fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

When I get this I usually just close it and reopen it, if that doesn't solve it then I log out and log back in, usually one of these fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a bug ;-)

The **[blog post](https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows)** which announces the release of "GitHub for Windows" states

> *We make sure to read every mention on Twitter.* **If you find a bug, submit it to support@github.com.** *Every email is read by a real person.*

"GitHub for Windows" is very frequently updated with bugs fixes and improvements. In order to get this fixed as soon as possible, I'd strongly suggest you to send them an email.

Comment: Thought so I too. Would be great to have a public solution to the problem here. I've sent them an email linking to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Thi issues's gone. The problem was with outdated libiconv-2.dll placed in c:\windows quite a while ago that caused conflict with the same DLL from GIT. As soon as I dropped the old one, GIT started working with flying colors!

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact error when the credit card on the account was outdated.

To check if this is the case for you (paid accounts only of course), go to the website github.com, log in with your account, and check the header. If there is a red error text mentioning your credit card, there you go.

Here's the exact text:

> We are having a problem billing your credit card. Please enter a new
>   card or call your credit card provider for details on why the
>   transaction failed. You can contact support@github.com with any
>   questions.  Your private repositories have
>   been locked until you fix this error. Thanks for
>   understanding.