# Failed to clone repository on Windows 8

Tags: git, github, git-clone, github-for-windows

I am new to Github and Git all together, and so I have downloaded the Github for Windows to run on my Windows 8 computer. However, when I attempt to clone a repository that is in an organisation that I am a member of, it comes up with the following message straight away:

```
failed to clone the repository 'foo/bar'
Please check your internet connection.
```

I can connect to the internet, and to Github.

Why is Github for Windows doing this? Is it a bug or something wrong with setting it up?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865110/unable-to-clone-this-repository-in-windows-8-rc-with-github-for-windows

Comment: @Pigueiras That is nothing like this question. Firstly, the answer is that it is fixed in v1.0.8.4, and I have the latest, and also in my case the error happens instantly, whereas in that question it starts cloning and then stops.

Comment: Check your local firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this error by re-installing Github for Windows. It is now working.

Comment: I installed Github for Windows fresh. Cloning didn't work for me. I had put a copy of PortableGit from the installation path into a new directory and put that into the %path% environment variable, so with that I ran a git clone command from command line. That worked. But this goes to show that GitHub for Windows is broken for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Are you behind a firewall? If so, set your Windows environment variables. Make sure to use lowercase for the variable names.

```
http_proxy=http://yourproxy.com:1234
https_proxy=http://yourproxy.com:1234
```